# Project File mystery - Duplicate Configuration Sections?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, projects-and-solutions

We are changing a large # of projects from x86 to AnyCPU. I don't know that it matters but these are .vbproj files. So i open one of our projects and change it from x86 to AnyCPU for All Configurations (We only have two: Release & Debug) and then i go look at a diff of the project file and i'm a little confused. There are two ProjectGroups with the same name:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>
    </DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>42353,42354,42355</NoWarn>
    <WarningsAsErrors>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036</WarningsAsErrors>
    <BaseAddress>1349517312</BaseAddress>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <RegisterForComInterop>false</RegisterForComInterop>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>
    </DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>42353,42354,42355</NoWarn>
    <WarningsAsErrors>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036</WarningsAsErrors>
    <BaseAddress>1349517312</BaseAddress>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <RegisterForComInterop>false</RegisterForComInterop>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <BaseAddress>1349517312</BaseAddress>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <NoWarn>42353,42354,42355</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <WarningsAsErrors>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036</WarningsAsErrors>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <BaseAddress>1349517312</BaseAddress>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <NoWarn>42353,42354,42355</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <WarningsAsErrors>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036</WarningsAsErrors>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

As you can see one ProjectGroup is set to compile to AnyCPU and another is set to compile to x86. Through the IDE everything is set to AnyCPU.Like i said there is only two configurations (release & debug) and one platform (x86). Yes i know the platform does not match `<PlatformTarget>` but that should not make a difference (different projects in our build will have different platform targets anyways).

This is possibly going to cause me two issues:

1. I was wanting to do a search/replace to change all project files from `<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>` to `<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTaget>` so i don't have to open every single project in visual studio.
2. Also also wanted to search to make sure i didn't miss anything

Comment: Well, that's not good, hard to guess how that happened unless you did this with a text editor.  Which is by far the fastest way to do this.  Probably best to restore them from source control and delete the useless extra $(Platform) instead.

Comment: This wasn't the only one :). I can't guarantee every single project file was like this but there was a LARGE number. How long they were like this no one knows. The only fix would be to strip out the duplicates in a text editors (if it turns out they are duplicates)

Comment: If you can't restore (eek) then, yes, you can only use a text editor.  Keep in mind that the compiler used the merged properties of both sections so you can cause breakage by deleting a section.

Comment: I decided to do a test and delete what i considered to be the orphaned entries. I then made some changes to the project config to see they would return after i resaved them in visual studio and they didn't. Maybe in this situation visual studio is reading from the top to bottom and the lower ones override the upper level ones. Very interesting but something thats going to cause me a lot of work :(

Comment: thanks Hans i guess i know what i need to do...YIKES

Comment: If anyone is curious i went through the history and i found the developer that tried to make a mass change to the project file when we originally switched to x86 and he changed all 'Release|AnyCPU' with 'Release|x86' and didn't realize  back then we had multiple Platforms back then (so we had 4 VALID entries) and thats what caused the issue.